# Advertised Data too Large Eddystone Beacon

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, beacon, eddystone

I am trying to make an android application that is able to advertise UID frames based on Eddystone Protocol. The Code for which is as follows

```
private void advertise() {
    //To check if Bluetooth Multiple Advertising is supported on the Device
    if( !BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().isMultipleAdvertisementSupported() ) {
        Toast.makeText( this, "Multiple advertisement not supported", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
        start.setEnabled(false);
    }

    BluetoothLeAdvertiser advertiser = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().getBluetoothLeAdvertiser();
    //defining the settings used while advertising
    AdvertiseSettings settings = new AdvertiseSettings.Builder().setAdvertiseMode(AdvertiseSettings.ADVERTISE_MODE_BALANCED).setTxPowerLevel(AdvertiseSettings.ADVERTISE_TX_POWER_HIGH).setConnectable(true).build();

    //We make Parcel UUID(UUID can be generated online) and Advertise Data object
    ParcelUuid pUuid = ParcelUuid.fromString("4db3d4ff-eda4-46e8-bd89-9a7b1f63cc83");

    //building servicedata
    byte txPower = (byte) -16;
    byte FrameType = 0x00;
    byte[] namespaceBytes =toByteArray("01020304050607080910");
    Log.e("nB",Integer.toString(namespaceBytes.length));
    byte[] instanceBytes =toByteArray("AABBCCDDEEFF");
    Log.e("instanceIdlength",Integer.toString(instanceBytes.length));
    ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
        os.write(new byte[]{FrameType,txPower});
        os.write(namespaceBytes);
        os.write(instanceBytes);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    byte[] serviceData =os.toByteArray();
    Log.e("Service Data Length",Integer.toString(serviceData.length));
    Log.e("ServiceData",serviceData.toString());

    AdvertiseData ADdata = new AdvertiseData.Builder().addServiceData(pUuid,serviceData).addServiceUuid(pUuid).setIncludeDeviceName(false).setIncludeTxPowerLevel(false).build();

    Log.e("Data",ADdata.toString());




     //callback to check success or failure when advertising
    AdvertiseCallback advertisingCallback = new AdvertiseCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onStartSuccess(AdvertiseSettings settingsInEffect) {
            super.onStartSuccess(settingsInEffect);
            Log.e("BLE","Advertising");
            status.setText("Advertising");
            status.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
            }
        @Override
        public void onStartFailure(int errorCode) {
            Log.e( "BLE", "Advertising onStartFailure: " + errorCode );
            super.onStartFailure(errorCode);
            status.setText("ErrorCode: "+errorCode);
            status.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            }
    };

    advertiser.startAdvertising(settings, ADdata, advertisingCallback);
}

private byte[] toByteArray(String hexString) {
// hexString guaranteed valid.
int len = hexString.length();
byte[] bytes = new byte[len / 2];
for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
  bytes[i / 2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(hexString.charAt(i), 16) << 4)
      + Character.digit(hexString.charAt(i + 1), 16));
}
return bytes;}
```

I have followed all the guidelines for frame length.

```
InstanceID:6bytes
NameSpaceID:10bytes
```

But I am still not able to advertise data because of Error Code.... `:ADVERTISE_FAILED_DATA_TOO_LARGE`

Is there anything I am missing here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect the problem is that the service uuid you are inserting in the advertisement is ending up being a full 16-byte Service UUID instead of the required 2-byte short Service UUID of 0xFEAA.  There isn't enough room for a full 16-byte Service UUID, which is why you get this error.

I struggled with this a bit when building Eddystone [transmission support in the Android Beacon Library](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/beacon-transmitter.html), and ended up copying a function from AOSP shown below.  You can see how it is used by the library below.

```
int serviceUuid = 0xFEAA;
byte[] serviceUuidBytes = new byte[] {
   (byte) (serviceUuid & 0xff),
   (byte) ((serviceUuid >> 8) & 0xff)};
ParcelUuid parcelUuid = parseUuidFrom(serviceUuidBytes);


/**
 * Parse UUID from bytes. The {@code uuidBytes} can represent a 16-bit, 32-bit or 128-bit UUID,
 * but the returned UUID is always in 128-bit format.
 * Note UUID is little endian in Bluetooth.
 *
 * @param uuidBytes Byte representation of uuid.
 * @return {@link ParcelUuid} parsed from bytes.
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException If the {@code uuidBytes} cannot be parsed.
 *
 * Copied from java/android/bluetooth/BluetoothUuid.java
 * Copyright (C) 2009 The Android Open Source Project
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0
 */
private static ParcelUuid parseUuidFrom(byte[] uuidBytes) {
    /** Length of bytes for 16 bit UUID */
    final int UUID_BYTES_16_BIT = 2;
    /** Length of bytes for 32 bit UUID */
    final int UUID_BYTES_32_BIT = 4;
    /** Length of bytes for 128 bit UUID */
    final int UUID_BYTES_128_BIT = 16;
    final ParcelUuid BASE_UUID =
            ParcelUuid.fromString("00000000-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
    if (uuidBytes == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("uuidBytes cannot be null");
    }
    int length = uuidBytes.length;
    if (length != UUID_BYTES_16_BIT && length != UUID_BYTES_32_BIT &&
            length != UUID_BYTES_128_BIT) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("uuidBytes length invalid - " + length);
    }
    // Construct a 128 bit UUID.
    if (length == UUID_BYTES_128_BIT) {
        ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.wrap(uuidBytes).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
        long msb = buf.getLong(8);
        long lsb = buf.getLong(0);
        return new ParcelUuid(new UUID(msb, lsb));
    }
    // For 16 bit and 32 bit UUID we need to convert them to 128 bit value.
    // 128_bit_value = uuid * 2^96 + BASE_UUID
    long shortUuid;
    if (length == UUID_BYTES_16_BIT) {
        shortUuid = uuidBytes[0] & 0xFF;
        shortUuid += (uuidBytes[1] & 0xFF) << 8;
    } else {
        shortUuid = uuidBytes[0] & 0xFF ;
        shortUuid += (uuidBytes[1] & 0xFF) << 8;
        shortUuid += (uuidBytes[2] & 0xFF) << 16;
        shortUuid += (uuidBytes[3] & 0xFF) << 24;
    }
    long msb = BASE_UUID.getUuid().getMostSignificantBits() + (shortUuid << 32);
    long lsb = BASE_UUID.getUuid().getLeastSignificantBits();
    return new ParcelUuid(new UUID(msb, lsb));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your valuable insight. Correct me if I am wrong.
As per what you mentioned , UUID generated is too long to be set as service UUID. Instead the method that you mentioned will provide the required length of service UUID?
The code I wrote was based on Google Eddystone repo on git : [link](https://github.com/google/eddystone/blob/master/eddystone-uid/tools/txeddystone-uid/TxEddystone-UID/app/src/main/java/com/google/sample/txeddystone_uid/MainActivity.java) Being new to it , I find it odd that there's no mention about this there. Is it something that's understood by default ?

Comment: Interesting, yes, I see this is in the reference code.  Perhaps some Android versions do not properly parse this as a two byte UUID: `ParcelUuid.fromString("0000FEAA-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");`

Comment: Your solution works as required. I am no longer facing the issue. Thanks

Comment: Great!  Out of curiosity, what SDK are you targeting and what Android version is your phone?  It's curious that Google recommends using `ParcelUuid pUuid = ParcelUuid.fromString("4db3d4ff-eda4-46e8-bd89-9a7b1f63cc83");` and it did not parse as two bytes for you.

Comment: Minimum SDK is 21 as BLE advertising is supported only for SDK 21 and above. Target SDK version is not an issue as all devices released post 2015 should mostly support BLE advertising.
The phone that I used for testing was One Plus 3(Android 6.0.1). As you could see in the code , as recommended , I am using `isMultipleAdvertisementSupported()` to check compatibility. The only issue I was facing was parsing of the UUID.